# Error when installing R package

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I'm starting to learn/use R. I'm using RStudio and I've come across what I'm sure is a "dumb question" but I've had no luck with looking on CRAN or anywhere else.

I'm trying to install a package. I've downloaded the package and placed it in a folder `R\Packages' in My Documents. I've written this script in RStudio to get the package working

```
install.package("knitr", lib="C:\Users\dnthompson\Documents\R\Packages")
```

but I get an error that says

```
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
```

Whats up with this?

Comment: You need to use "/" instead of "\" in file paths.

Comment: brand new error `Error: could not find function "install.package"

Comment: its `install.packages` :)

Comment: Haha, like I said, "dumb question" 
Judging by the loads of things that just ran through my console, I think it worked! Thank you!